# Object is undefined while using bcrypt

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

I am trying to hash passwords, but the object I am binding the function to is undefined. Why so? How to resolve it?

route:

```
app.post('/users',(req,res)=>{
  let user = new User();
  user.username = req.body.username;
  user.password = req.body.password;
  user.email = req.body.email;
  user.save((err)=>{
    if(err)
   res.send('Username or email already exists');
   else
   res.send("User Created Successfully")
  }); //through mongooose
})
```

Bcrypt function && mongoose middleware

```
UserSchema.pre('save',(next)=>{
  let currentUser = this;
  console.log(currentUser.username); //getting undefined here
  bcrypt.hash(currentUser.password,null,null,(err,hash)=>{
    if(err) return next(err);
   currentUser.password = hash;
   next();

  })
})
```

Comment: Not an answer, but before creating hash for password you should check if password has been modified ( `this.isModified('password')` ). Otherwise you will create hash from hash from hash ....

Comment: The context is undefined i.e "this" is undefined. How to resolve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use es6 `arrow-function`, Instead use anonymous function as below:

```
UserSchema.pre('save',function(next){
   let currentUser = this;
  console.log(currentUser.username); //getting undefined here
  bcrypt.hash(currentUser.password,null,null,(err,hash)=>{
    if(err) return next(err);
    currentUser.password = hash;
    next();
  })  
})
```

When you use arrow function `this` won't be the user object instead it will be Schema object.

Answer (score 1):

Try below method which uses async/await to encrypt the password:

```
userSchema.pre('save', async function save(next) {
  try {
    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
    this.password = hash;
    return next();
  } catch (error) {
    return next(error);
  }  
})
```

Comment: it's also possible that it's comes due to bcrypt bindings problem.

https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/issues/280